# Raspbian Stretch with Desktop vs Rasbian Stretch Lite Install Problems

Tags: raspbian, pi-b+, desktop, raspbian-lite

I had an older pi (B+ model) running Raspbian Jesse and ran into a corruption issue, and finally picked it back up to replace the SD Card and I have been having issues installing Raspbian Stretch with Desktop. Originally I wrote the img file to the SD Card using Etcher and later installed it via Noobs, but each time it got hung up on different error messages. Mainly:

```
---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs unknown-block(179,7)
random: crng init done
```

After trying this 4-5 times I transitioned to Raspbian Stretch Lite, and this installed successfully with no problem. After this was successful I tried with Desktop again, but it got hung up on the same error message again. Can anybody help explain:

> ```
> ---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs unknown-
> block(179,7)
> random: crng init done
> ```

What is this error message and is there any way I can correct it?

**NOTE:** I am using the pi with a connected monitor & keyboard. I cannot ssh into the pi because the ip address isn't being assigned. I am using an 8GB Micro SD Card.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one on Stack Exchange. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions, so that we can address each point separately in detail. Thanks!

Comment: Question 2 is also likely answered [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40854/58316); give it a go, and if not, post a separate question with detail for that problem.

Comment: You can add the Pixel desktop to raspbian lite with `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods` or use `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends raspberrypi-ui-mods lxterminal gvfs` for a stripped down version.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I apologize for my newbie move, I will make sure to separate my questions in the future. I was under the assumption that we had a limit on questions.

Comment: @1QuickQuestion No problem, and you probably are rate limited on questions (1 every 40 minutes if I remember correctly), but as long as your questions are received well by the community, you'll be able to continue asking more. The 40 minutes between questions gives you time to research and make sure each question is as good as it can be. Make sure you check all your questions on this site to see if there's a duplicate around, too, and you should be able to get an answer if not. Good luck!

Comment: @bobstro for some reason I had an error installing both versions, a "hault" message. I will have to run it again to get you the full line error if you need it.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I honestly don't know how to mark this, because in the midst of trying the [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40854/58316) provided I reinstalled Scratch with Desktop (again) and it installed successfully. Now it's just weird behavior waiting for the Desktop to actually display.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: As Aurora has already stated: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks... and while [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39932/19949) is for Jessie, the difference of "standard" vs. "lite" is likely to be the same... See, separate questions for specific issues work best on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

The error `---[end Kechallengernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs unknown-block(179,7)
random: crng init done`

is often mentioned when a corrupt image have been transferred to a SD card or when a SD card is faulty or kernel bugs.

I have replaced a corrupt SD card due to this cause and that solved my challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities are:

1. Your SD card is corrupted–try another one.
2. Your image was corrupted when you downloaded it.
3. Your kernel has problems.
4. Other problems related to formatting your SD card. Sometimes you have to go to [sdcard.org](http://sdcard.org) and download software to format your SD card in the best way posible.